# Getting error "Attempt to execute SCRIPT sum as a function" whenever I open any other file in MATLAB script

Tags: matlab, runtime-error

Whenever I try to open any MATLAB script in the MATLAB editor, instead of opening the script, it gives me the following error -

```
  Attempt to execute SCRIPT sum as a function:   /home/home_shihab/Documents/MATLAB/sum.m
     Error in imformats>find_in_registry (line 511)   switch (sum(match))
     Error in imformats (line 113)
          varargout{1} = find_in_registry(fmts, varargin{1});
     Error in imread>parse_inputs (line 464)
              fmt_s = imformats(varargin{2});
     Error in imread (line 322)   [filename, fmt_s, extraArgs, was_cached_fmt_used] = parse_inputs(cached_fmt, varargin{:});
     Error in matlab.ui.internal.dialog.DialogUtils.imreadDefaultIcon (line 39)
              [iconData, ~, alphaData] = imread(iconFileName, 'BackgroundColor', 'none');
     Error in msgbox>setupStandardIcon (line 446)   [iconData, alphaData] = matlab.ui.internal.dialog.DialogUtils.imreadDefaultIcon(iconName);
     Error in msgbox (line 361)
          Img = setupStandardIcon(IconAxes, IconString);
     Error in errordlg (line 59)   handle = msgbox(ErrorStringCell,dlgName,'error',replace);
     Error in uiopen (line 202)
      errordlg(err);
```

The problem is that, I am not trying to run the file sum. I have navigated to a completely separate directory and i'm trying to open a different file. Also, the file which I'm trying to open, doesn't even link to the 'sum' file.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Don't call a `sum` `sum`, nor a `mean` `mean`, or a `max` `max`. Just rename the file and don't overload functions. It's going to bite back.

Comment: There is a set of core MATLAB functions like the ones Adriaan mentioned here that, if you shadow them (hide them by creating your own file with the same name or creating a variable of that name), all sorts of things will stop working. You should never create an M-file with the name of a built-in function in MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. I understand that but why does it care if I have a file named 'sum' in a completely unrelated folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the issue by simply renaming the 'sum' file in the Documents/MATLAB/ folder. I don't know how it was connected to the script that I was trying to open and I also don't know why that folder was being watched by MATLAB in the first place, but it worked. :D